# Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() WordPress 4.2.2 RSS Feed

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, domdocument

I'm getting **Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName()** now when I'm trying to pull in the RSS feed from my wordpress blog. Here's the code I'm using to get the RSS feed (which has worked up until recently):

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
        @$xmlDoc->load('http://www.revolutionpersonaltraining.com.au/blog/feed/');
        $x      = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

        for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++):
            $items[$i]['date']  = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime($x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue));
            $items[$i]['title'] = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $items[$i]['link']  = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $items[$i]['desc']  = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        endfor;
```

If anyone could shed any light on this, that would be fantastic.

Comment: $x->item($i) may not be a document. Can you use . instead of ->, The syntax is document.getElementsByTagName('') na.

Comment: I'm getting the same error if I use a . instead of ->

Comment: Same error.. Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this way :

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load('http://www.revolutionpersonaltraining.com.au/blog/feed/');


$items = array();
foreach ($feed->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) {
    array_push($items, array ( 
        'title' => $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    ));
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: I'm getting this (and my array is empty):

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::load(): CData section not finished <p>What the hell is Weightlifting? Isn&#8217;t it in http://www.revolutionpersonaltraining.com.au/blog/feed/, line: 51 in /home/revopt/public_html/modules/mod_wordpress/helper.php on line 36

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): PCDATA invalid Char value 24 in http://www.revolutionpersonaltraining.com.au/blog/feed/, line: 51 in /home/revopt/public_html/modules/mod_wordpress/helper.php on line 36

Comment: I opened it up and I viewed the source, and the RSS is all in there.. Is this a Wordpress problem?